# ruby - iterating through aws instances/volumes and creating nested hash structure

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk

Using aws-sdk, I need to discover instance_ids and all the attached volumes. I then want to iterate over those volumes.

`@instances` contains a list of instance id's. This is needed because filtering first needs to be done client side.

```
@ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new

@instances.each do |instance_id|
    resp =  @ec2.describe_volumes({ 
        filters: [{
           name: 'attachment.instance-id',
           values: [instance_id]
        }]
    }).volumes
    resp.each do |volumes|
        (@volumes[instance_id] ||= []) << volumes.volume_id
    end
end
```

This works fine. My output is something like:

```
{
  "i-11111111": [
     "vol-xxxxxxxx",
     "vol-xxxxxxxx",
     "vol-xxxxxxxx"
  ],
  "i-22222222": [
     "vol-xxxxxxxx",
     "vol-xxxxxxxx",
     "vol-xxxxxxxx",
     "vol-xxxxxxxx",
     "vol-xxxxxxxx"
  ],
  "i-33333333": [
     "vol-xxxxxxxx"
  ],
  "i-44444444": [
     "vol-xxxxxxxx",
     "vol-xxxxxxxx"
  ]
}
```

The problem is that I would like to go deeper, and change the array of volumes to a hash with the volume-id of that key.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Client.html#describe_volumes-instance_method

It would look like

```
{
  "i-11111111": {
     "vol-xxxxxxxx": [
         device: "/dev/blah1",
         attach_time: "blah"
     ],
     "vol-xxxxxxxx": [
         device: "/dev/blah2",
         attach_time: "blah"
     ]
  },
  "i-22222222": {
     "vol-xxxxxxxx": [
         device: "/dev/blah1",
         attach_time: "blah"
     ],
     "vol-xxxxxxxx": [
         device: "/dev/blah2",
         attach_time: "blah"
     ],
     "vol-xxxxxxxx": [
         device: "/dev/blah3",
         attach_time: "blah"
     ]
   }
}
```

I could then query the hash for the required information (assuming that's possible?)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this:

```
resp.each do |volumes|
  volume_ids = volumes.map(&:volume_id)
  descriptions = @ec2.describe_volumes(volume_ids: volume_ids)
  volume_hash = (@volumes[instance_id] ||= {})
  descriptions.each { |desc| volume_hash[desc.volume_id] = desc }
end
```

This assumes:

- that the format of the `volume_ids` option is an array; I was not clear from the docs whether it should be an array or a string
- that none of the other options listed in the `describe_volumes` API docs are necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'json'

client = Aws::EC2::Client.new

instances = ['i-instanceone', 'i-instancetwo']

volumes = client.describe_volumes({ 
  filters: [{
     name: 'attachment.instance-id',
     values: instances
  }]
}).volumes

list = volumes.flat_map(&:attachments).each_with_object(Hash.new {|k,v| k[v] = {}}) do |vol, hsh|
  hsh[vol.instance_id][vol.volume_id] = {
    device: vol.device,
    attach_time: vol.attach_time
  }
end

puts JSON.pretty_generate(list)

# {
#   "i-instanceone": {
#     "vol-one": {
#       "device": "/dev/sda1",
#       "attach_time": "2015-02-25 14:24:23 UTC"
#     }
#   },
#   "i-instancetwo": {
#     "vol-two": {
#       "device": "/dev/sda1",
#       "attach_time": "2015-04-27 13:08:14 UTC"
#     },
#     "vol-three": {
#       "device": "/dev/xvdf",
#       "attach_time": "2016-04-10 14:45:15 UTC"
#     }
#   }
# }
```